# Running into a memory error using Perl and DateTime

Tags: perl, datetime

I am writing a small tool to parse some application logs for to collect data that is going to be used as the inputs for Zabbix monitoring. I am just wanting to keep data from the logs that are within the past two hours.

The format of the logs is pretty simple, the fields are separated by white space and the first three fields are used to determine the time when the logging was written.

Here is an example of the first three fields of a log line:

Jan 5 13:42:07

What I set out to do was to utilize one of my favorite modules, DateTime. Where I convert the above into a DateTime object and then compare that object to another DateTime object when the utility would be invoked.

Everything was fine an dandy and working nicely until I actually set the utility against the a portion of the logs it would actually be parsing -- only a couple gigabytes in size. The test run was being done on a kitchen invoked Ubuntu virtual box instance on my laptop, so the resources are -- as expected -- rather limited. The script would halt with the words 'Killed' displayed.

Looking into /var/log/messages I would see log lines describing the process being killed due to resource issues.

When I invoked the process again, and then switching to another screen instance to watch top, I noticed that the memory percentage would grow, that swap space would being to be consumed all until the script would again stop with the 'Killed' message.

When I would rerun the script with the DateTime portion commented out, the script would execute as expected.

In the script I have a subroutine which would be called to create a DateTime object based upon the information found in the first three fields of the log line. I have tried where I create the object at the beginning of the subroutine then undef it prior to returning a value at the end of the subroutine, I have tried it where I create a global object ( using our ) and then use the DateTime set_* methods to modify what I thought would be a single object's values.

I have read that perl does not clean up hash memory so that it can be reused by the program--I feel that this is the base of the issue that I am running into.

At this point, I am feel the need to get input of others and that is the reason for this post. All comments and criticisms would be appreciated.

This utility was running on Perl v5.14.2.

This code produces the memory leak:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DateTime;

my $month  = 1;
my $day    = 6;
my $hour   = 20;
my $minute = 30;
my $second = 00;

for (my $count = 0; $count <= 25_000_000; $count++) {
    my $epoch = &get_epoch( $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second );
}

sub get_epoch {
    my $mon = shift;
    my $day     = shift;
    my $hour    = shift;
    my $min     = shift;
    my $sec     = shift;

    my $temp_dt = DateTime->new(
        year       => 2015,
        month      => $mon,
        day        => $day,
        hour       => $hour,
        minute     => $min,
        second     => $sec,
        nanosecond => 500_000_000,
        time_zone  => 'UTC',
    );

    return( $temp_dt->epoch );
}
```

Comment: presumably running the script with everything *but* the DateTime portion removed still uses increasing memory?  show us the shortest actual runnable code (and sample data) that reproduce the problem.  The solution is likely to be something simple, but without seeing your code there's no way to tell what it is.

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will write some code to reproduce the issue.

I should state for ysth that running the code without the DateTime portions does not cause the memory issue, it is only when the DateTime usage is in effect that the problem shows up.

Comment: Some version of DateTime use an old version ParamsValidate, which causes the memory leak. Make sure you have up to date DateTime. Test if this cause a memory leak: use strict; use warnings;

use DateTime;

while (1) { DateTime->now }

Comment: @Myforwik,

Thank you for the response and test.  I am running it but do not see a memory leak.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DateTime;

my $month = 1;
my $day = 6;
my $hour = 20;
my $minute = 30;
my $second = 00;

for( my $count = 0; $count <= 25000000; $count++ ) {
  my $epoch = &get_epoch( $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second );
}

sub get_epoch {
  my $mon = shift;
  my $day = shift;
  my $hour = shift;
  my $min = shift;
  my $sec = shift;
  my $temp_dt = DateTime->new(
    year => 2015,
    month => $mon,
    day => $day,
    hour => $hour,
    minute => $min,
    second => $sec,
    nanosecond => 500000000,
    time_zone  => 'UTC'
  );
  return( $temp_dt->epoch );
}`

Comment: the above produces the memory leak.

Comment: Put that in a pastebin and link it

Comment: Can't see any circular references, so if that example up in your post leaks then you've found a definite bug. Check you've got the most up to date version of the module and then file a bug report

Comment: @PeterR

~/bin# perl -MDateTime -e 'print "$DateTime::VERSION\n"'  
1.18  
  
Looks to be the current version.

Comment: I filed a bug through CPAN.

Comment: And you've got your answer direct from the maintainer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Params::Validate 1.15 and will be fixed very soon.